# How to navigate to Ruby/RSpec `shared_examples` in VSCode?

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, rspec

In Ruby/RSpec using VSCode, suppose I have a `shared_examples`

```
shared_examples "foo bar" do |blah|
   ...
end
```

then if I have somewhere else the line

```
it_should_behave_like 'foo bar', blah do
```

I would like to be able to put my cursor on that line and use the 'Go to Definition' functionality (F12 or so) to go to the `shared_examples` code.

I have installed the 'Ruby', 'Ruby Solargraph' and 'VSCode Ruby' extensions, but can't get this to work.  For ordinary Ruby functions and classes however, 'Go to Definition' works.

My current workaround is to search for "foo bar" and find and click the `shared_examples` in the search results, but that is inefficient.

Does anyone know how to make this work in VSCode?  Code browsing like that *is* possible in RubyMine...

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it's not (currently) possible (because no one has yet written that extension).

The long answer is...

"Go to Definition" needs to know of the structure of the code in order to work. Typically, this is done by parsing the files in the code to look for definitions of classes and methods. But...

Ruby is a dynamic language, meaning you can use meta-programming to alter the structure of the program at run time. So, it's not always possible to look at a file on disk and determine where the function lives. In fact, it might not exist at all. The code might be defining it at runtime.

RSpec uses meta-programming extensively. That's what allows it to call a shared example using only a string to find it. So, when you call this:

```
shared_examples "foo bar" do
  ...
end
```

Ruby is calling a method called `shared_examples` with a name (`"foo bar"`) and a block (`do ... end`). Inside that method, RSpec is registering that block in a registry (probably a hash) with the name as the key.

So, when you call this:

```
it_should_behave_like "foo bar" do
  ...
end
```

RSpec needs to look up the block defined by the call to `shared_examples` by the string `"foo bar"` under which it was registered before RSpec can call it. So, the shared example never really exists as an actual method on disk with a `def foo_bar` definition. This means that a generic tool that reads Ruby files and turns them into clickable method definitions will never find this method.

Alas, we would need an RSpec specific plugin to follow a shared example. I'm unaware of any such plugins at the moment.

Here's [the RSpec source code in question](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/main/lib/rspec/core/shared_example_group.rb#L90).